# How do I make bootstrap Collapse sections also submit a form?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with lots of areas that you can click to collapse, but I would like to save the users preferences for the parts they collapse in their account server-side so when they revisit the page the parts they collapsed previously will stay that way.

My problem is, I cant get the button to both collapse and submit a http post form in the background, I can do one or the other but not both at the same time on one button.

Here is the button the user clicks:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Section_1" name="button" value="save_collapse_choice_1"><strong>Section 1</strong></button>
```

And here is the section that would collapse in or open up

```
<div id="Section_1" class="collapse in">
This will collapse (And does)
</div>
```

Then I simply have a form called backend.php which is in the page and if I didn't have the data-toggle="collapse" on my button, then that form submits successfully with the name button and the value save_collapse_choice_1

Obviously when I have this in the actual page the class="collapse in" would have some PHP in there to add or remove the "in" part dependant on what setting is stored on the server for this users account.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: I apologise, I have now added that to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `$.ajax()` and post to the `backend.php` the value of the open/close divs and run the open-close in the same page?

Something like

```
$('button[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function() {
    /* open and close code */
    $.ajax() {
        url: 'backend.php&save-collapse-choice'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not very good with Javascript, how exactly would I use that? And where would I put the $.ajax() part? Sorry for my lack of experience.